# create an ext4 drive with GParted

Tags: gparted, usb-drive

When using `GParted` to format an `ext4` USB Flash drive, it seems sufficient to select `Parition > New`, rather than `Device > Create Partition Table`. That's good because after selecting "create partition table" it doesn't seem right to select `msdos` and none of the other choices seems obviously right. Instead, I proceeded to use `Parition > New` and then the `ext4` selection.

What happens in this case?

A. Is there no partition table on the device?

B. Is there some default partition table and if so, what kind?

C. Something else?

Answer (score 1):

If a partition table does not exist and is not created, then using Partition -> New will format the entire device with the selected file system.

See [GParted Manual - Creating a Partition Table](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-create-partition-table) to learn about the two most popular partition tables (msdos and gpt).