# mounted SSD not show in Logical Volume Management tool

Tags: partitioning, mount, ssd, lvm

I have a SSD attached and mounted on /media.

[image]

Now, for the same mount I want to create a Logical volume.

When I open my Logical Volume management tool, I dont see this /media mount being listed.

[image]

How can I have them listed under Logical Volumen Management tool.

Comment: You have to format the partition as LVM, not NTFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access existing files on that volume, you should *not* be attempting to use Logical Volume Management (LVM). In most cases, the desktop versions of Ubuntu will automatically mount NTFS volumes when you plug them in, or at least give you an icon you can use to mount these volumes. You can also use the `mount` command to mount them manually.

Note that NTFS is a poor filesystem choice for use with Linux. You should use NTFS only on disks that are shared with Windows. This could be removable disks that you move back and forth between computers or partitions used to store shared data on a dual-boot computer. If you intend to use the disk in a Linux-only environment, you should probably create a fresh Linux-native filesystem on the disk. This does not need to involve LVM. See, for instance, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384062/how-do-i-create-and-tune-an-ext4-partition-from-the-command-line/384063) or [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736090/create-an-ext4-drive-with-gparted/736410) for information on this subject.

LVM, by contrast, is used to make managing multiple filesystems easier, particularly in complex setups with multiple disks or when you need to frequently add, delete, or resize *Linux* filesystems. If you want to discard all the files on the disk's existing NTFS partition and use it as an LVM physical volume (PV), you can do so, but you'll need to learn about LVM to proceed. Note that, although LVM adds a great deal of flexibility and can simplify some operations, it has a significant learning curve when you're just starting out. Completely describing it in an answer on this site is therefore impractical. Instead, I suggest you read an existing Linux LVM tutorial, such as:

- [This one](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) on the Ubuntu wiki site
- [This more complete tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm) on HowtoForge
- [This one](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-lvm-logical-volume-manager) on LinuxConfig